# No overload for method 'OpenIdSelectorScripts' takes 2 arguments

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, compiler-errors, dotnetopenauth, openid-selector

I'm implementing openId to my project using mvc3 with razor,I get this error in my logon page:

logon.cshtml

```
@using DotNetOpenAuth.Mvc
@using DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.RelyingParty

@{ 
 ViewBag.Title = "Log On"; 

      var options = new OpenIdSelector();
      options.TextBox.LogOnText = "Log On";


}


<h2>Log On</h2>
    @(Html.ValidationSummary("Login was unsuccessful. Please correct the errors and try again."))

    <div id="login-oauth">
        <h3>via 3rd Party (recommended)</h3>

        @{ Html.RenderPartial("LogOnContent");}


    </div>
    <div id="or">OR</div>
    <div id="login-account">
        <h3>using a OnlineAB account</h3>
         </div>
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        <div>
            <p>
                <label for="username">Username:</label>
                @(Html.TextBox("username"))
                @(Html.ValidationMessage("username", "*"))
            </p>
            <p>
                <label for="password">Password:</label>
                @(Html.Password("password"))
                @(Html.ValidationMessage("password", "*"))
            </p>
            <p>
                @(Html.CheckBox("rememberMe")) <label class="inline" for="rememberMe">Remember me?</label>
            </p>
            <p>
                <input class="classiclogon" type="submit" value="Log On" />
            </p>
            <p>
                Please enter your username and password. @(Html.ActionLink("Register", "Register")) if you don't have an account.
            </p>
       </div>
    @MvcHtmlString.Create(Html.OpenIdSelectorScripts(options, null))
   @* @(Html.OpenIdSelectorScripts(this.Page, options, null))*@

    }
```

Server Error in '/' Application.

Compilation Error

Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

Compiler Error Message: CS1501: No overload for method 'OpenIdSelectorScripts' takes 2 arguments

Source Error:

```
Line 63:             </p>
Line 64:        </div>
Line 65:     @MvcHtmlString.Create(Html.OpenIdSelectorScripts(options, null))
Line 66:    @* @(Html.OpenIdSelectorScripts(this.Page, options, null))*@
Line 67:
```